# C++ Console Application, Outputting Incorrect Data

Tags: c++, output, visual-studio-2017, pseudocode

I've been working on a simple console application and was stopped when, upon compiling my latest code, it began outputting strings of text and integers which did not match what I have entered.

The purpose of the program thus far is simple: to input a string of data and for it to output correctly multiple times in the console application. Below I have linked the pseudocode.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printIntro();
void RunApp();
bool RequestRestart();

std::string GetAttempt();

int main() // entry point of the application 
{
    printIntro();
    RunApp();
    RequestRestart();

    return 0;
}

void printIntro() {

    // introduce the program
    constexpr int WORD_LENGTH = 8; // constant expression

    std::cout << "Welcome to the Bull and Cow guessing game\n";
    std::cout << "Can you guess the " << WORD_LENGTH;
    std::cout << " letter isogram I am thinking of?\n\n";

    return;
}

void RunApp()
{
    // loop for number of attempts
    constexpr int ATTEMPTS = 5;
    for (int count = 1; count <= ATTEMPTS; count++)
    {
        std::string Attempt = GetAttempt();

        std::cout << "You have entered " << GetAttempt << "\n";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

std::string GetAttempt() 
{
    // receive input by player
    std::cout << "Enter your guess: \n";
    std::string InputAttempt = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, InputAttempt);

    return InputAttempt;
}

bool RequestRestart() 
{
    std::cout << "Would you like to play again?\n";
    std::string Response = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, Response);

    std::cout << "Is it y?: \n" << (Response[0] == 'y'); //response must be in brackets

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Post your code directly instead of posting a picture of code.

Comment: I've posted my pseudocode directly

Comment: Are you supposed to print a *pointer to the function* `GetAttempt`, or what it have *returned* (and you stored in the `Attempt` variable)?

Comment: It's supposed to output whatever the user inputs into the console

Comment: In other words, you want to print the contents of the `Attempt` variable? So why don't you do that?

Comment: doesn't it already do that?

Comment: No, you print a pointer to the function `GetAttempt`. Perhaps instead of continuing this program you should [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and kind of start over, especially relearn how to use variables and functions.

Comment: I have started a course where I am currently learning *how* to do all of this. I have fixed the program thanks to users below. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this line 
`std::cout << "You have entered " << GetAttempt << "\n";`
in`std::cout << "You have entered " << Attempt << "\n";`

In this way you do not print the address of the function, just like you did before, but the variable in which you stored the return value of the `GetAttempt` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing a pointer to `GetAttempt`. Instead print `Attempt`:-

```
std::cout << "You have entered " << Attempt << "\n";
```